# Can CTAD be used inside a member of the template class?

Tags: c++, c++20, class-template, ctad

C++ has this helpful feature that says that the template parameter is implicit in the code inside a template class `A`.
However, for construction, this seems to clash with CTAD.

How can I make CTAD take precedence?

For example, here, there is an error in the `f` member because `A` is interpreted as `A<T>` where `T` is `std::string`, and not deduced from the parameter `double`.

```
#include<string>

template<class T>
struct A {
    A(T const& t) {}
    auto f() {return A{5.0};}  // error here triggered by line 11 `auto a2 = a1.f();`
};

int main() {
    A a1{std::string{"hello"}};
    auto a2 = a1.f();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3nc7nev3o

Comment: Use template lambda inside `f`?  Like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Mrnd4oG15)?

Comment: @Dmitry, that is like having a `make_A` function, but thanks!

Comment: yeahhh, in fact I would not recommend to use it! User-defined deduction guides can easily [break](https://godbolt.org/z/Y666b1ded) the expected behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `::A` to tell the compiler to use the name `A` from the global scope instead of using the name `A` in the class scope which is just shorthand for `A<T>`.  That gives you:

```
#include<string>

template<class T>
struct A {
    A(T const& t) {}
    auto f() {return ::A{5.0};}  // uses CTAD to return A<double>
};

int main() {
    A a1{std::string{"hello"}};
    auto a2 = a1.f();
}
```

as seen in this [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/rcjMGTj73).

---

Another option is to add a private alias to the class type and then use that alias in the function as needed.  That gives you:

```
#include<string>

template<class T>
struct A {
private:
    template <typename U>
    using NewA = A<U>;
public:
    A(T const& t) {}
    auto f() {return NewA{5.0};}  // uses CTAD to return A<double>
};

int main() {
    A a1{std::string{"hello"}};
    auto a2 = a1.f();
}
```

and can bee seen working [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rKr96sed8)

Comment: Mmm, yes, that works. https://godbolt.org/z/hvG1r9EdT. However, now the class needs to know the namespace to which it belongs. Not ideal.

Comment: @alfC If you are defining the class, don't you know which namespace you are in?

Comment: Yes, but if I later refactor the namespace, I have to change the internals.

Comment: @alfC I get that.  I just added another option

Comment: right, I discovered it at the same time. (version 2 in my answer). Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately, the template typedef cannot be put inside the function, but nonetheless, this is the best option, IMO.

Comment: @alfC Yeah, it can't be at function scope but at least with it being a private alias no one else needs to know about it and you can use it in other functions in the same class if needed.

Comment: In retrospect, our elders had `rebind` typedef for some classes (notably for allocators). This is just an evolution of it. This is a rebind upgraded to a template typedef and exploited by CTAD. https://godbolt.org/z/sPcMb3jWG . Perhaps `rebind_t` is a better name. Can be even be useful publicly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I can define a template typedef and **hope** the CTAD works through it.

```
#include<string>

template<class T>
struct A;

template<class T> using A_CTAD = A<T>;

template<class T>
struct A {
    A(T const& t) {}
    auto f() {return A_CTAD{5.0};}  // error here triggered by line 11 `auto a2 = a1.f();`
};

int main() {
    A a1{std::string{"hello"}};
    auto a2 = a1.f();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hex79s91a

but it doesn't seem to be a big gain compared to using the good old `make` function.
https://godbolt.org/z/j3PTW7MWY

---

Version 2, make an internal template typedef, not bad. No need for forward declarations.

```
template<class T>
struct A {
    A(T const& t) {}
private:
    template<class TT> using CTAD = A<TT>;
public:
    auto f() {return CTAD{5.0};}  // error here triggered by line 11 `auto a2 = a1.f();`
};
```